# ng-pattern not working with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

My form has below inline validation

```
<form name="coForm" novalidate> 
<div>
   <label>Transaction: </label>
   <input  type="text" name="transaction" class="form-control"
           placeholder="<Direction> <Message Type>, ex.:OUT X12214" 
           ng-model="newco.transaction" 
           ng-pattern=/(^(IN )([A-Za-z0-9 &_]+))|(^(OUT )([A-Za-z0-9 &_]+))/ 
    required>

      <span style="color:red" 
         ng-show="coForm.transaction.$dirty || 
                  coForm.transaction.$invalid">
      <span ng-show="coForm.transaction.$error.pattern">
          Enter correct value for Transaction
      </span>
      <span ng-show="coForm.transaction.$error.required">
            Transaction is required.
      </span>
</div>
</form>
```

But the validation works only for `required` and not for `pattern`

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivB/pwan5L0g/)

Below are the few examples for positive match:

```
OUT X12214
In X12850
IN ARRANT
OUT CORREC&TRANSLEG
OUT TEST_TEST
IN TEST2&TEST2
```

Comment: before to ask question please indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing double quotes on of `ng-pattern` attribute & also you have not initialize angular on page, you need to add `ng-app` to run angular on page

**Markup**

```
<form name="coForm" novalidate ng-app="">
    <div>
        <label>Transaction:</label>
        <input type="text" name="transaction" class="form-control" placeholder="<Direction> <Message Type>, ex.:OUT X12214" ng-model="newco.transaction" 
        ng-pattern="/(^(IN )([A-Za-z0-9 &_]+))|(^(OUT )([A-Za-z0-9 &_]+))/" required>   
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="coForm.transaction.$dirty || coForm.transaction.$invalid">
           <span ng-show="coForm.transaction.$error.pattern">Enter correct value for Transaction</span>
            <span ng-show="coForm.transaction.$error.required">Transaction is required.</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwan5L0g/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
ng-show="coForm.transaction.$dirty && 
              coForm.transaction.$invalid">
```

Comment: This is not working. I have added one more simple field in my form, that is not working in the jsfiddle as well. But the newly added field `CO Number:` works in my application. [Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivB/pwan5L0g/5/)